# Passing arguments to java function in bulk

Tags: java, function, arguments

What would you use if you wanted to pass a list of options into a function?

For example, if you have an interface to a server:

```
public interface Server {
    public void authUser(String username, String password, <xyz> options);
}
```

What structure would use use for  to pass a set of options? Something like a HashMap?

The reason I'm saying that it comes from tunnel vision is because I feel that this goes against Java standards. Java has method overloading. So if I get flames for raising the question I understand. But overall, maybe in different cases, would you ever pass bulk data in some collection and, if yes, which one?

Comment: Yes you can pass bulk data in any type of collection object this is not a problem...what exactly is your question?  The data structure would depend on what data you are passing...

Comment: Also what does method overloading have to do with this question?

Comment: Hashmap, ArrayList, LinkedList, Array, Properties Object these are a few data structures you could use to pass data...

Comment: It goes case by case but sometimes bulk data passing is used to allow flexible parameters that are optional. As such, I mentioned that language's ability to overload methods provides better alternative, sometimes :)

Comment: I guess I don't quite get what your question is?

Comment: Whether passing in bulk is a bad approach and I should reconsider the design. Also, if it is acceptable, what data type is best to be used. I will not pass complex data in the options and it will only be primitive. I will also not transmit data so I don't need to use jsonobject or equivalent. So I guess that Hashmap would be best?

Comment: Yes passing bulk data should be fine...it still depends on what your data is like a Hashmap would be for key,value pairs.  If you are just passing primitive data types then I would recommend using an array or create your own custom class consisting of String[], int[], double[] etc...whatever you need to pass then create one object with all your data and pass it in that way.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option1** : If you are choosing any collections like List or Set these are specific to an object . I mean,

Lets Assume, Set sets = new HashSet();
If I want 5 Object of different different class having no relationship  to be send, then It would be very difficult to recognize that which Object is belong to which class while Iteration. So, I wont recommend Collections.

**Option2** : If you are choosing Map, the same above problem may occurs while getting the Object Dynamically. So, This Options is also not recommended.

**Option3** :

*Why cann't you create your own DTO and in that DTO place your reqyired datastructure and pass it over.*

If you want 5 different Object to be pass then, you can pass. If all are of same type then you may use Collection or array or Variable Arguement based on your scenerio.

Answer (score 0):

I think anything Serializable is exactly the thing. If you can serialize the object, then you can pass (store, transmit...) it, passing it's properties in bulk. What format of serialized data to choose, is another question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you want to pass.

1. You can use a map(hashmap) if you are passing key-value pairs.
2. If it is just a list of diffrent object, you can use List(ArrayList)
3. Other option is to create DTO(data transfer object) with getter and setter methods.
4. You may want to take a look at VARARGS feature that was introduced in JAVA5.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a Map [HashMap] as you can then access the argument values via their Keys.